# Is it possible to allow users to see only the files/folders they have created in a windows (server 2016 ) shared folder?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, network-share

a shared folder has been created z://networkshare/workfolder/

user1 has created a file file1.doc and saved to z: drive

user2 has created a file file2.doc and saved to z: drive

Currently both users can see both files. But I would like to restrict user1 to see only file1.doc and user2 only see file2.doc

Is this possible?

Comment: I have exactly the same question. Can you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with Access-Based Enumeration.

[image]

You will need to configure NTFS permissions appropriately, which can be tricky: the users will need to be able to create files (and/or folders), but they will also need to *not* be able access files they don't own; you'll also need an ACE which grants full control on new files  to their creator, which is represented by the virtual username `CREATOR OWNER`.

If permissions are configured correctly and ABE is enabled, users will only be able to see files and folders to which they have access.